# Which is the best way to filter List?

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I have this simple class structure:

```
Vehicle
|-- Bus
`-- Car

Bus and Car extends Vehicle
```

I have `List<Vehicle>`. How can I get only buses or cars? I would like to avoid `instanceof` operator. Do I have to use Visitor pattern or is there any simpler solution?

Comment: If you define a `List<Vehicle>` and then have logic that requires you to just access `Bus`es in there, then it *might* suggest a design problem. You may want to consider having a separate list for each subclass although I can see that there are situations where this might not be appropriate.

Comment: @Qwerky I have been thinking about two lists but the problem is that at some point I have to decide which list I add new vehicle in. Also, it would make me to implement separate methods for each type or use `instanceof` anyway. I want to avoid all of this in case of adding a new type of vehicle. And the only place where I need to determine the type is getting a list of the particular vehicle so I don't want to spread the particular types through the whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well *something* will need to use `instanceof` or an equivalent (such as `Class.isInstance`).

[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a method which does exactly this though: [`Iterables.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29). So you could use:

```
List<Bus> buses = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(vehicles, Bus.class));
```

Comment: And is the usage of `instanceof` in this case correct or bad design?

Comment: @Tom - I'd say it depends on why you're filtering.  If you want just the buses because you're going to apply some ticket-related logic to them, then it would be better design to have a `public boolean carriesPassengers();` (or similar) method on the `Vehicle` interface, and filter on that.  If you want the buses for a *specifically* Java-class-related reason (maybe controlling the details of serialisation or somesuch?), it's not so bad from a design viewpoint.

Comment: @Tom: *Sometimes* this sort of thing is unavoidable, but it really depends on *exactly* what your scenario is.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I just want to render them separately in two tables. This is the only reason I want to filter them. Should I use the `instanceof` then? I've been always told that `instanceof` is kind of _evil_ so I want to avoid it if it is possible.

Comment: @Tom - it still depends on why you're rendering them separately; what characteristic are you conceptually separating them on?  For example, a table for "memory usage by class" to be used for debugging - absolutely fine.  On the other hand, separating them because one is "big" and the other is "small" should again be done via a discriminator method on `Vehicle`.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Every type of vehicle should have its own table - because of clarity. It's the only reason. If I use the method as you say, it means that every particular vehicle should implement it and says something like _I'm a car_? And this is good design?

Comment: @Tom: You *could* have an enum of "vehicle types" and a method on Vehicle to return the relevant enum value. It ends up being pretty similar to checking with instanceof, although more flexible in some cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet This seems fine. Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

I see no way to avoid the use of `instanceof` operator in your case, nor can I see a way to produce much simpler code than this (without help from Guava) :

```
List<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<Bus>();
for (Vehicle v : vehicles)
    if (v instanceof Bus)
        buses.add(v);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want instanceOf add field to Vehicle that determine class.